# Имя собственное: Роман

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Что значит имя Роман? Откуда пришло к нам, как звучит в оригинале, насколько древнее, какие корни и первоисточник имени, кого таким именем нарекали и т.д.?

Comment: Корни и первоисточник имени — не одно и тоже? Кого таким именем нарекали... В каком смысле?

Answer (score 1):

[ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/роман](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F_11) :

> Происходит от франц. roman «роман», далее из ст.-франц. romanz
>   «романский; роман», далее из лат. Romanus «римский», далее из Roma
>   «Рим», далее из неустановленной формы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать, что  происхождение оно имеет очень древнее.

Если обратиться к языку латинскому, то он поведает о том, что имя Роман происхождение ведет от слов **«римлянин» и «римский».** В те времена родиться римлянином означало огромную удачу, так как это наделяло человека многими льготами и защитой на территории всех завоеванных римскими воинами стран и государств. Быть римлянином означало быть человеком с большой буквы, которого примут во внимание в любом обществе и интересы которого будут соблюдены при любых обстоятельствах. Не только патриции, но и плебеи, имевшие удачу родиться в Риме в те далекие времена, обеспечивались привилегиями и почетом. Престижный статус, который определяло римское гражданство, приносил свои бонусы тем, кто носил имя Роман. Происхождение при этом играло определяющую роль: те, кто носил это прозвище, имели на него право только если рождались в вожделенной столице империи, поэтому уже само имя открывало для его носителя многие двери.

Таким образом, назваться Романом означало быть человеком, имеющим права, власть и преимущества.

В греческой трактовке имя Роман происхождение ведет от слова, которое означает силу и крепость. Таким образом, **в переводе с греческого Роман – «крепкий» и «сильный».**

Имя это имеет как положительные стороны, так и отрицательные. 
К положительным свойствам имени можно отнести следующие качества:

•   легкий нрав и жизнелюбие;

•   остроумие; веселость и умение радоваться;

•   широту интересов;

•   талантливость;творческие навыки;

•   незлобивость; доброту;

•   способность учиться новому.

Характеристика имени Роман обширна. Это прозвище делает своего носителя легким на подъем для принятия решений. Роман не будет долго мучиться, переживать, взвешивать и анализировать. И, что самое интересное, большинство спонтанных решений приводят к положительным результатам. К отрицательным свойствам имени можно отнести такие качества, как:

•   неумение держать язык за зубами, то есть болтливость;

•   непостоянство и влюбчивость;

•   импульсивность и ненадежность.

Имя Роман характер своему обладателю "подпортил" и ленью, которая нередко становится преградой в достижении целей. А ведь достаточно постараться - и желаемое станет действительным. Таким образом, главный враг того, кого зовут Романом, – это его лень, которая может даже пустячную преграду превратить в настоящую гору проблем.

Те, кто носит это древнее имя, имеют предрасположенность к респираторным заболеваниям, болезням желудка и склонны к аллергии. По этой причине обратите внимание на состояние своего здоровья и принимайте различные профилактические меры для борьбы с осложнениями. Вы сохраните жизненный тонус и сможете избежать многих хронических болезней.

Скучные науки и «просиживание» в офисе не придутся Роману по нутру, поэтому профессии, не предполагающие познавание нового, открытий, передвижений и знакомств, можно сбросить со счетов сразу же. Что касается собственного бизнеса, то Романы слишком щедры, чтобы стать по-настоящему богатыми. Их природной добротой всегда найдутся желающие воспользоваться, поэтому будьте бдительны и аккуратны, чтобы самим не оказаться в долгах. Кстати, что касается карьеры военного, то тут Роман вполне может себя реализовать.

**Ещё один вариант толкования:**

http://www.alltaro.ru/names/men/Roman.html

Имя Роман происходит от латинского слова "романус" - римлянин, римский; от греческого - крепкий.

ИМЕНИНЫ И СВЯТЫЕ ПОКРОВИТЕЛИ РОМАН
Роман Самосатский, мученик. Казнен за обличение языческого вероисповедания в Сирии. В русском народе ему молились об избавлении от бесплодия и бесчадия, 11 февраля (29 января).
Роман, князь угличский, строитель храмов и богаделен в суровые времена монгольского ига, 16 (3) февраля.
Роман страстотерпец, 15 (2) мая.
Роман Олегович, рязанский князь, мученик, 1 августа (19 июля).
Роман Римский, мученик, 23 (10) августа.
Роман Константинопольский, сладкопевец, творец канонов, диакон, получивший в дар от Богородицы умение слагать церковные гимны и песни, 14 (1) октября,
Роман Кесарийский, Антиохийский, священ но мученик, диакон, 1 декабря (18 ноября).
Роман Антиохийский (Сирийский), отшельник, чудотворец, творивший чудеса исцеления, 10 декабря (27 ноября).

ЗНАК ЗОДИАКА РОМАНА - Телец (Водолей).

ПЛАНЕТА-ПОКРОВИТЕЛЬ РОМАНА - Сатурн.

ЦВЕТ ИМЕНИ РОМАН - Лиловый, красный, красно-лиловый - символ активности интеллектуальной и физической

КАМЕНЬ-ТАЛИСМАН РОМАНА - Аметист.

РАСТЕНИЕ РОМАНА - Имя Роман отождествляется с тополем, кипарисом и фиалкой.

ЖИВОТНОЕ РОМАНА - Лань, бабочка-парусник.

ОСНОВНЫЕ ЧЕРТЫ ХАРАКТЕРА РОМАНА - Воля и трудолюбие, интеллект,

ТИПАЖ РОМАНА - Эти загадочные люди обладают талантом убеждать других. Роман настолько рассудителен, что временами кажется нудным. Очень организован и терпелив.

ХАРАКТЕР ИМЕНИ РОМАН - Роман не выносит никакого однообразия. Роман влюбчив. Его страстный, изобретательный ум, любовь к разнообразию станут суровым испытанием и одновременно радостью для той, с кем он свяжет жизнь. С ним всегда весело. Он не упрямец н не диктатор, легок на подъем, щедр и добр с людьми.

ПСИХИКА РОМАНА - Никогда не забывает нанесенных ему обид. Не поддается влиянию, объективен. Делу отдается полностью, правда, если существует такая необходимость. Самоуверен.

ИНТУИЦИЯ РОМАНА - Обладает прекрасной интуицией.

МЫШЛЕНИЕ РОМАНА - Он более интеллектуален, чем кажется. Действует скрытно, дергая за веревочки из-за кулис.

НРАВСТВЕННОСТЬ РОМАНА - Всегда стремится к тому, чтобы быть свободным. Ни в коем случае не хочет связывать себя моральными нормами. Резко отрицательно относится ко всему, что могло бы помешать его делам.

ЗДОРОВЬЕ РОМАНА - Хорошее, хотя может страдать от диатеза. Должен следить за органами пищеварения.

СЕКС И ЛЮБОВЬ РОМАНА - В отношении секса у него возникает много проблем, так как эти мужчины не умеют и не хотят ждать. Их желания скорее основаны на инстинкте, чем вызваны любовью.

БРАК И СЕМЬЯ РОМАНА - Роман будет счастлив в браке с Анной, Валентиной, Еленой, Любовью, Майей, Марией. А вот союз с Евгенией, Екатериной, Оксаной, Тамарой вряд ли будет удачным. Правда, возможны и варианты..
УВЛЕЧЕНИЯ И ХОББИ РОМАНА - Человек с этим именем не терпит жизненного однообразия. Он вполне может оставить институт за полгода до окончания и податься на заработки или же пренебречь полученным дипломом, например ради карьеры непрофессионального актера. Увлекшись чем-то, он загорается, способен увлечь и других людей. Ему нравятся боевые виды спорта: борьба, каратэ, регби.

РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ В ОБЩЕСТВЕ У РОМАНА - Роман находит удовлетворение в работе, если она хорошо оплачивается. Хотел бы исследовать неизвестные области. Может стать непревзойденным разведчиком, миссионером, полицейским, политическим деятелем.
КАРЬЕРА И БИЗНЕС РОМАНА - Потенциальными кандидатами в удачливые предприниматели являются Романы, отцов которых зовут Андрей, Дмитрий или Петр.

ВЕЛИКИЕ ЛЮДИ - Балаян, Виктюк, Кармен, Карцев, Леденев, Рябцев, Ткачук.

Comment: «Назваться Романом означало быть человеком»? Надо попробовать, вдруг сработает и сейчас. Потеряю паспорт, но человеком стану.